# A regular expression to match a string in double quotes like this "name":"some_name"

Tags: javascript, regex

given a var jsonString = JSON.stringify({
    "where" : {
    "age" : "20",
    "name" : "josh",
    "phone": "999",
    "email":"email"
    }});

I created the following pattern string

```
const pattern = `"${propertyName}":"${value}"`;
```

the `propertyName` and `value` are variables.

I need to match a string like `"name":"some_name"` including the double-quotes.

so I made a regular expression like this `new RegExp(pattern,'i')` but it does not work.

I need help with this.

I need to find if jsonstring contains `"name" : "josh"` and `"age":"20"` and so on..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to ask a specific question. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for understanding what kind of questions are good to be asked here. There are also many good online tutorials on regex which should you get you started nicely. There are even online regex interpreter where you can enter your sample string and then interactively develop your regex.

Comment: You can use [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) function.

Comment: I can't use json.parse() in that situation.

Comment: Please help me any one!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could use

```js
var strToSearchIn = '{"where":{"age":"20","name":"josh","phone":"999","email":"email"}}';

/*var pattern=/"([^"]*)":"([^"]*)"/g;*/
var patternName=/"name":"josh"/g;
var patternAge = /"age":"20"/g;
var regex = new RegExp(patternName,'i');
var regex2 = new RegExp(patternAge,'i');
var corresp = regex.exec(strToSearchIn) + regex2.exec(strToSearchIn);

if(corresp != null && corresp!=0){
 /* found something */
 console.log('ok');
}else{
  /* not found */
  console.log('not ok');
}
```

So you just have to replace josh by the name you need
and 20 by the age you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

here below a sample code to write your regexp.

Your new RegExp should be with the pattern.
If i test it, .exec will return an array of 3 elements :

- first one the complete string
- second one the first part of your property
- third one the last part of your value

```js
var str = '"${propertyName}":"${value}"';
var pattern=/"([^"]*)":"([^"]*)"/g;
var regex = new RegExp(pattern,'i');
console.log(regex.exec(str));
```

Hope it was what you asked for.

Comment: It did't worked. Can you please give another solution.

Comment: I want to check if the string `"{"where":{"age":"20","name":"josh","phone":"999","email":"email"}}"` has a substring `"age":"20"` or `"name":"josh"` with regular expressions and dynamically using variables

Comment: Please help me in this.